# Crystal Reports Issue with DLL

Tags: dll, crystal-reports

I have an issue when deployed to the server (Works fine in Local Machine).
Error Details :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application expects the Crystal Reports Runtime for .NET Framework Service Pack 20. Make sure you deploy that runtime to the target machine.

For download links and details, see: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads